# Initial Block Download Problem

Tags: testnet

I started a new Bitcoin Core(testnet) and the download of blocks worked perfectly till 15% and then i don't know what happened, but i got the following error:
unknown new rules activated (versionbit 1)
What should i do?
[image]

Comment: It seems that sync is finished, if you look at the picture i uploaded.

Comment: I cannot use any other Option

Comment: This is really busted.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error that has halted progress, the sync is continuing.

Warnings are informational messages that may need attention.